# automatically enable bluetooth discoverability, when app is opened?

Tags: javascript, ios, bluetooth, cross-platform, discoverability

What code can I use for my phone app to automatically enable bluetooth discoverability, every time the app is opened?

I would like to do this on multiple platforms - at least the main vendors. So if the necessary code is different for each, maybe a javascript method would be best, if possible. Because I will be using phonegap to translate it for each platform in the end anyway.

Edit:
The user will be informed about how the app works before they download it. The goal is just to improve usability, by minimizing the amount of effort by the user eg. navigating other menus in their phone to enable bluetooth themselves, considering that is only one of several features this app will make use of on their phone. I just did't explain that at first because I'm new here and I got the impression the question should just focus on code. But anyway, thats the situation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can do this on any (protected) platform,...
I don't think any mobile OS would allow this, because of the security and privacy issues, imagine you visit a website and all of a sudden without your permission your bluetooth is on and discoverable.